# MySQL - Subquery returns more than 1 row (Strange one)

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I am facing Strange problem.

I am trying to update a record in my table.  I am updating by using primary key (Unique and Not null).

**Here is the query:**

```
UPDATE `rxMaster` SET `Name`='Ac Electri' WHERE `rxMasterID`=13493;
```

**Getting following Error:**

```
ERROR 1242: 1242: Subquery returns more than 1 row
SQL Statement:
UPDATE `rxMaster` SET `Name`='Ac Electri' WHERE `rxMasterID`=13493;
```

I am sure, I have only one record in database with ID '13493'.  I am not sure what is going on.

Correct me If I am missing any thing.

**Note:** if I create new record and update that record no issues.  But if I tried to update an old record, I am getting this.

**Trigger:**

```
-- trigger for drop and update a record in rxMaster table, affected in search_text table. --
DELIMITER $$ 
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `tr_upd_rolodexSearch`$$ 

CREATE TRIGGER `tr_upd_rolodexSearch` AFTER UPDATE on `rxMaster` 
    FOR EACH ROW 
        BEGIN 
            CALL sp_rolodex_upd_searchindex(NEW.rxMasterID, NEW.Name, NEW.SearchName, NEW.Phone1); 
        END$$ 
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: there is no subquery in this. There's nothing wrong in updating multiple rows.

Comment: Why is this a subquery to what?

Comment: Please double check your query by applying `SELECT * from `rxMaster` WHERE `rxMasterID`=13493;`

Comment: Don't you have a trigger `ON UPDATE` on the table, maybe there's a query that executes and returnes more rows there.

Comment: I am pretty sure I don't have duplicates. Please see now, I added a screenshot.

Comment: Check if there is any TRIGGER associated on UPDATE of that table

Comment: Yes I have a Trigger, But it is working fine if I create new record and update it.  Problem is with old records.

Comment: @vissu Take a look over the queries in the trigger and see which one returnes duplicates. Or post the trigger's code here.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu, Sorry I tried by dropping trigger also.  Still same problem :(

Comment: It's definetly a problem with a subquery returning more than 1 result, and if that doesn't appear in a query you're executting, it's definetly in a trigger. Are you sure there are no other triggers on the talbe?

Comment: I have added my trigger and SP both in question.  Please guide me if I am doing any wrong.

Comment: try running just the queries that set the values for the variables in the stored procedures and see if there's at least one that returnes duplicates.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu, I Dropped the trigger and tried also.  Still same problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38862/discussion-between-radu-gheorghiu-and-vissu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be a `ON UPDATE` trigger has a subquery which returns more than 1 result, and it shouldn't.

You will have to look over the queries in the trigger and run them to see which returnes duplicates.

Then, either modify the trigger or see if there are indeed duplicate entries in your tables and remove those (only if there shouldn't be duplicates).

Comment: Sorry, I am dropping 'On Insert' trigger accidentally. Now I dropped Update trigger and working fine.  I will correct my update trigger.  Thank you very much for your help.